# Empty json file when serialising with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to serialize a Student object into a student.json file,
in my code it's student.

The main idea is that i create a json string , create a student from it then again make a json string but from the student object and finally serialize the student object to a json file.

here is my code :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
public class JaJson {

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        System.out.println("Hello");  
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mahesh\", \"age\":21}"; 

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
        builder.setPrettyPrinting(); 

        Gson gson = builder.create(); 
        Student student = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Student.class);
        System.out.println("student object");    
        System.out.println(student);    

        jsonString = gson.toJson(student);
        System.out.println("student string");  
        System.out.println(jsonString); 
        String sFileName = "student.json";
        try{
    //Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(sFileName));
    //gson.toJson(student, writer);
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
            gson.toJson(student, writer);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println (ex.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
        }

    }  
    public JaJson(){
        System.out.println("what time is it ?");
    }

}
```

here is Student.java

```
public class Student { 
   private String name; 
   private int age; 
   public Student(){} 
   
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
   }
   
   public void setName(String name) { 
      this.name = name; 
   } 
   
   public int getAge() { 
      return age; 
   }
   
   public void setAge(int age) { 
      this.age = age; 
   }
   
   public String toString() { 
      return "Student [ name: "+name+", age: "+ age+ " ]"; 
   }  
}
```

Here is the output of the program :

> ```
> Hello
> student object
> Student [ name: Mahesh, age: 21 ]
> student string
> {
>   "name": "Mahesh",
>   "age": 21
> }
> ```

But it produces an empty student.json i don't understand ...

Any idea what is missing ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add :

```
    writer.flush(); //flush data to file   <---
    writer.close(); //close write
```

in my code as :

```
try{
    //Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(sFileName));
    //gson.toJson(student, writer);
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);
            gson.toJson(student, writer);
            writer.flush(); //flush data to file   <---
            writer.close(); //close write  
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println (ex.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
        }
```